# Webpack/Typescript with common my scripts

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm making project that consists of 3 subdomains. Every has it's own webpack configuration, own IDE (PhpStorm) project and so on.
For every subdomain I have common `typescript` scripts (my own - not node_modules).

I don't want to copy my code three times - I want to use one source.
What is the best aproach for that? Should I publish every script using npm? I don't want that.

If I import script pointing to correct file `import {Mapa} from "../../../../www/assets/js/mapa/Mapa";` it works but looks very ugly.

**Edit:**
I'm trying the `tsconfig` approach with no luck.
Here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "C:\\strony\\www\\libsJs\\*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

If I import file like `import {ExampleTest} from "Example/src/index";` I get Module not found. But whe I switch to `import {ExampleTest} from "../../../../../libsJs/Example/src/index";` all works...
What can be issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use local paths as NPM dependencies ([docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths)).
Or you can create symbol links to add you shared folder to each of your subprojects, so it'll appear as if it's copied.

**EDIT**
It's also possible to use `rootDirs` and `paths` in `tsconfig.json` of each subproject, to make import statements prettier.

Comment: Thanks for anwser - I'm fighting with `tsconfig`. Please see Edit above.

Comment: @piernik, I can't see any problems with your example, a combination of `"baseUrl"` and `"paths"` should work. Try to compile with `tsc --traceResolution`, it will show exactly why it can't resolve to `C:\strony\www\libsJs\Example\src\index.ts` file in your case.